# How can I identify what node my python program is running on?

Tags: python, python-2.7

My research lab has access to 24 nodes from my schools cluster. Sometimes my programs run significantly faster then other times and I want to try to diagnose the problem by finding out what nodes they are running on to see if some are slower then others. What is the best method, using python, to have my output file also tell me what node the program was computed on?

Comment: Im not sure, try `import platform; print platform.node()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`Platform`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/platform.html) module. Integrate a couple simple functions in your `Node()` class

```
import platform

class Node(object):
    ...
    def get_device_os():
        """ Get the devices operating system. """
        return platform.system()


    def get_device_name():
        """ Get the devices name. """
        return platform.node()
```